# Log recording with tail -f

Tags: linux, tail

Is there any function in linux's `tail` utility that lets use save a recording. The scenario is:

- At current line in log, start recording
- Do operation that can generate logs, or many logs
- Stop and save recording

There is always possibility to use it on screen, but working with remote logs is painful at times and it can always be useful to have specific capture that is smaller in size and make it easier for following a certain operation and troubleshooting-

Is there any other work around that can be used?

Comment: `tail -f /some/file | tee /some/other/file`?

Comment: Log files often contain the date and time information and maybe keywords or IDs related to a process/service. Instead of recording parts of the log file you could extract the time range and or keywords relevant for the operation afterwards, e.g. using `awk` with time specifications as start and stop patterns.